# Java Date tests failed - same but not

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

could u explain me why those unit tests are failed?
The code seems to be very obvious and even the fail result shows the same.

```
@Test
public void getFormatedDate() {

    Date date = new Date();
    assertEquals(date, dateRestService.getFormatedDate(date));
}
```

And the console log is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.util.Date<Sun Jan 07 17:06:05 CET 2018> but was: java.util.Date<Sun Jan 07 17:06:05 CET 2018>
Expected :java.util.Date<Sun Jan 07 17:06:05 CET 2018> 
Actual   :java.util.Date<Sun Jan 07 17:06:05 CET 2018>
```

getFormatedDate as expected:

```
@Override
public Date getFormatedDate(Date dateToBeFormated) {

    dateToBeFormated = date.getDate();
    dateToBeFormated = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

    return dateToBeFormated;

}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without knowledge of  `getFormattedDate`. Try `assertEquals(date.getTime(), dateRestService.getFormatedDate(date).getTime());` and you will probably see that to `Date`s don't represent same timestamp. The you have just shows that the `toString()` of both objects are equal to each other, not that the objects themselves are equal.

Comment: Are you sure the milliseconds are also the same?

Comment: Post edited, getFormatedDate added.
Methods toString() seem to be equals but getTime() miliseconds are different.
Is there any other proper method to test it?

Comment: Your method could be inlined to `return new Date();`. You can of course test that, but I would concentrate on the logic first, and make the code less convoluted, and more correct. Start by adding javadoc on the method to specify what it **should** do.

Comment: Currently `getFormattedDate() ` just creates a new date, without even taking into account the original date passed. Seems weird, but definitely explains why test fails. Actually, It's great that your test fails as it uncovers a clear bug ;-)

Comment: Also, the first line of the function refers to an undeclared variable `date`.

Comment: @MaciejPapurzyński, if you need to check milliseconds you could test like this: `Assert.assertEquals(d.getTime(), getFormatedDate(d).getTime());` And if I run your code I see this `junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 

Expected :1515376622610

Actual   :1515376622611`

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are instanciating two Date objects in different moments so they are supposed to be different. Probably they have different milliseconds that may not be seen when formatting the dates. To assert that your method is returning the today date value probably you need to check field by filed, assert year, month, day, hour, minutes and seconds.

Comment: And what if second date is created in another second as the first? Not so good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getFormatedDate` function should be more like this:

```
public static String getFormatedDate(Date inDate) {   
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z Y", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String dateString = format.format(inDate);
    return dateString; 
}
```

When given the current time when this answer was written, it returns "Sun Jan 07 14:50:16 EST 2018", which seems to be in the format that your assert expects.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
instant.equals( Instant.now() )   // Capture the current moment with a resolution as fine as nanoseconds, and compare.
```

## Fractional second

Your call to `Calendar` is capturing another moment, a later moment, than the passed `Date`. Both capture the current moment with resolution of milliseconds. So while they both might be capturing the same second, the fractional second may differ or may be identical depending on speed of your computer. You are generating a String showing only whole seconds and so would mask any difference in fractional second.

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the modern java.time classes.

### Nanoseconds

Capture the current moment in UTC as a `Instant` with a resolution as fine as nanoseconds depending on the capability of your hardware clock, in Java 9 and later. In Java 8 specifically, the current moment is captured only as fine as milliseconds, with an older implementation of `Clock` that got replaced in Java 9.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

### Use objects, not strings

Compare the objects directly, not strings.

```
boolean isEqual = instant.equals( Instant.now() ) ;  // Likely FALSE.
```

### ISO 8601

To generate a String for display to humans, call `toString` for text in standard ISO 8601 format with as many digits in the decimal fraction as needed to show current value. So no hidden data.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;  Generate String in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 2018-01-23T01:23:45.123456Z